# Converting int to char[]

Tags: c, arrays, printf

So I am attempting to convert two dates (today's date and this date from 10 years ago) from the integers of year, month, and day, into two strings "YYYYMMDD\n".

Everywhere I look suggests to use sprintf, but I am running into trouble and I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the buffer.

Here is my code:

```
void main()
{

char today[9];
char ten_years[9];
int year, tenyear, month, day;

time(&timebuf);
tm = localtime(&timebuf);

year = (tm->tm_year%100)+2000;
tenyear = year-10;
month = tm->tm_mon+1;
day = tm->tm_mday;

sprintf( today, "%04d%02d%02d\n", year, month, day );
printf("today(first print)= %s\n",today); //This prints as expected

sprintf( ten_years, "%04d%02d%02d\n", year, month, day );

printf("today(second print)= %s\n",today);  //Now this prints null
printf("ten_years= %s\n",ten_years); //This prints fine

}
```

So obviously, in calling sprintf the second time, it's for some reason nulling out the "today[]" array.
Can anyone help me figure out how to stop this from happening?  Is there a better way to convert these dates to char[]?

I need the dates in char[] format because they have to be sent to a function that accepts char[] as the parameter (I have no control over the receiving function).

Edit: As per the suggestions I used the simpler formatting structure, but that does not solve the issue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202030/discussion-on-question-by-bk-32-converting-int-to-char).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need space for the null terminators in your strings. You don't allocate enough space for them, so the next string in memory is "erased".

To fix this, allocate 10 characters instead of 9:

```
char today[10];
char ten_years[10];
```

use `snprintf`, and include a field width:

```
snprintf( xxx, sizeof(xxx), "%04d%02d%02d\n", year, month, day );
```

If, on the other hand, you don't want to include a newline in your string, you can keep the size of the arrays you had previously and remove the newlines from your `snprintf` statements:

```
snprintf( xxx, sizeof(xxx) "%04d%02d%02d", year, month, day );
```

---

An unrelated problem; this will fix the Y2.1K bug present in your code:

```
year = tm->tm_year + 1900;
```

As `tm->tm_year` is relative to 1900, this should fix some issues with your code in the next century.

I would advise making `year`, `month`, and `day` `unsigned` and printing them with `%u`; this may fix some issues with negative years a few eons from now:

```
snprintf( xxx, sizeof(xxx) "%04u%02u%02u", year, month, day );
```

Another unrelated issue; `void main()` is invalid. Instead, you should be using `int main(void)` and putting `return 0;` at the end of your `main` function.

Also note that you do not need to manually null-terminate your strings. This is already done automatically in C.

Comment: Please explain how a string of 8 chars plus 1 null terminator equals 10 and not 9?

Comment: @bk_32 The newline counts too. 4 chars for year, 2 chars for month, 2 chars for day, 1 char for newline, and 1 char for a null terminator.

Comment: Got it.  I was confusing \n with "null terminator".  What I should have been putting was \0?

Comment: @bk_32 No, strings are null-terminated automatically. All you need is `\n`.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need \n.  I was trying to null terminate the string.

Comment: @M.M That's apparently a minimum, though, as mentioned above. That's a wonderful idea to use `snprintf`, I'll add a note about that. (Also, can't wait to see when that'll happen.)

Comment: @M.M: Are you messing with your system time again?? 8vD

Answer (score 2):

If you try to compute the destination size for a `sprintf` call exactly, down to the last byte, you will have problems like this all the time.  Trying to be so scrupulously parsimonious about every last byte is "false economy" and typically a huge waste of time.

Unless you're programming for a 1960's-era microcontroller, or something, do yourself a favor and allocate 10-50% more than you need.  If you were to declare

```
char today[15];
char ten_years[15];
```

most of your problems would just immediately vanish.

Buffer overflow is a huge problem, though.  So there's a second, even more important fix you should make.  Replace those calls to `sprintf` with the much safer `snprintf`:

```
snprintf( today, sizeof(today), "%04d%02d%02d\n", year, month, day );

snprintf( ten_years, sizeof(ten_years), "%04d%02d%02d\n", tenyear, month, day );
```

Besides a buffer pointer, `snprintf` also accepts an argument specifying the *size* of that buffer, so that it can be sure not to overflow it.

---

One more thing: It has nothing to do with your buffer overflow problem, but there's another pretty serious problem in your code, namely the line

```
year = (tm->tm_year%100)+2000;
```

The `tm_year` field is defined to contain *the year - 1900*.  This is admittedly an odd definition, but it means that the right way to restore a proper, 4-digit year is just to do

```
year = tm->tm_year + 1900;
```

The code you had would compute the wrong year for dates in the 1900's, or 2100's, or any date not in the 2000's.